# Make recursive all C files

Tags: c, makefile

I really can't get into makefiles. In previous projects, I hardcoded all compile tasks in the **Makefile**:

```
all: compile_a compile_b compile_c

compile_a:
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${A_SRC} -o ${A_OUT}
```

and so on.

But as the latest project has *more files* than every project before, I want to write better make tasks and of course LESS characters as make is not really friendly to my eyes (it makes them suffer)! :-P

What I want:

- One task to rule them all (just `make projectname` or `make all`, you know?)
- One task for every C file to compile (I read something about this `%.o: %.c` syntax, but didn't really get it)
- One task for linking (how to get all .o files and link them without hardcoding each?)
- One task for cleaning (oh, i can do this!)

The project structure is:

```
bin (binary goes here!)
src
  some
  directories 
  are
  here
```

I don't know if I need a directory for object files, I put them in `./bin`, I think that's good enough, isn't it?

Maybe I just need someone who can explain it with easy words!

EDIT:
As someone pointed out, there's no real question, so here it goes:

- how to recursively compile all C files to `bin/(filename).o`
- how to link all `.o` files in 'bin/' without knowing their names

maybe this helps.

Comment: You didn't really ask a question.  Which part are you having trouble with?  What do you really want to do?

Comment: It's more work than it looks like to set up a decent build system with makefiles. Try a build tool like CMake or SCons. **Edit:** The hard part is getting the dependencies between `.c` and `.h` files into the Makefile, there are tools that help with that but it's messy. [See this article](http://make.paulandlesley.org/autodep.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -c -Wall -g -Os
LD = $(CC)
LDFLAGS = -lfoo

TARGET = MyProject

OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard *.c))

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
        $(LD) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

# You don't even need to be explicit here,
# compiling C files is handled automagically by Make.
%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

clean:
        rm $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
```

Comment: Well, I think I understand the `%.o` syntax now, but how to call it for, let's say `./src/foo/bar/somefile.c` ? - EDIT: Forget it, I think I've got this part!

Comment: I think that should be `$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)`, with the linking happening in that recipe, and then `all: $(TARGET)` with no explicit recipe. Otherwise, there's no recipe to build MyProject, which "all" depends on.

Comment: This doesn't fully answer the OP's question, which asked for a *recursive* Makefile. This will just compile everything in the top-level folder.

Comment: @JamieBullock That's pretty easy to fix: instead of `$(wildcard ...)`, one could use `$(shell find . -name "*.c")`.

Answer (score 11):

I frequently use the `wildcard` function in combination with the `foreach` function for something like you want to achieve.

If your sources are in `src/` and you want to put the binaries into `bin/` the basic construction of my `Makefile` would look like follows:

```
SOURCES=$(shell find src -type f -iname '*.c')

OBJECTS=$(foreach x, $(basename $(SOURCES)), $(x).o)

TARGET=bin/MyProject

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
```

I usually take advantage of make's built in implicit rules and predefined variables ([Make manual, Chap 10](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules)).

Comment: This would put all `.o` files in the source tree, but I think it's better to put them into the `bin/`, isn't it?

Comment: I don't see the advantage of all object files located in a separate folder. If it's just to see no overpopulated folder after an `ls` there are other ways to go around. Also i can't remember any program i compiled that had a separate folder for object files.

Comment: how do you handle header file dependencies, especially if the headers are in a separate folder?

Answer (score -6):

without going into specifics of makefiles, use the * to your advantage.

i.e.

```
compileAll:    gcc -c *.c
linkAll:       gcc *.o -o output.exe
```

Comment: Won't work: 1) the second line will only use the `*.o` files that happen to be there 2) it assumes everything is in the same directory. Besides, the output files should be targets of the rules.